# Placing a div class on top of a three.js scene to create a gui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

How would I place a div class on top of my three.js class to create html buttons. I have a div currently acting as the container for my scene. Then I want to place more div classes on top of that scene to create guis and buttons. Currently running code like this:

```html
<div id="world">
 <div id="test">
  <button>hi</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

This places a button on the top of the page followed by the scene and not the button inside of the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div` you want to put on top must have `position: absolute` and `z-index` higher than the bottom `div`. For example:

```
<div id="world">
    Three.js Container
    <div id="test">
        <button>Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#world { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
}

#test {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
}
```